# How to send only Xamarin.iOS executable to friend in development team

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin.iOS Console Application and an Xcode ObjC app that opens (ie. runs) the Xam console app.

I want to send to a friend the ObjC project and only the Xamarin.iOS executable because friend doesn’t know Visual Studio.

Where is the Xamarin console app executable (ie. path and which files) and how does friend install it?

Here is how ObjC app runs the Xam app executable:
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"XamariniOS://"]];

In the Xam project, I set:
Info.plist > Advanced > URL Types > URL Schemes = scheme name = “XamariniOS“

Comment: what is a "Xamarin.iOS Console Application"?

Comment: when you use Visual Studio to create a Xamarin.iOS console application project.  The application type in the project properties is "Console Application".  IE. Visual Studio > solution > add > new project > Add a new project > template types > "iOS app (Xamarin)"

Comment: Ad-Hoc Distribution for Xamarin.iOS Apps -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/ad-hoc-distribution?tabs=macos

Answer (score 0):

> Where is the Xamarin console app executable (ie. path and which files) and how does friend install it?

As SushiHangover's said, you could distribute the Xamarin.iOS Application as **[Ad-Hoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/ad-hoc-distribution?tabs=macos)** mode. Then you will get an `.ipa` file. You could send it to your friend, then he can open and install the Xamarin.iOS application in your friend's iPhone.

The detailed steps to distriute a Ad-Hoc ios app, you could refer to shared official document to know.

> Ad hoc distribution has the advantage of not requiring App Store approval, and it can be installed over-the-air from a web server, or via iTunes. It is, however, limited to 100 devices per membership year, for both development and distribution, and these must be manually added in the Member Center by their UDID.

In addition, if you are a member of the *Apple Enterprise Developer Program*, you also
also could distribute it as *[In-House](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/in-house-distribution?tabs=windows#testing-your-application)* mode to send it to your friend.

Comment: Thanks. Am not enterprise. Am now trying ad hoc distribution...

Comment: @DougNull Great, if works let me know that. And if the reply is helpful, please do not forget to accept it as answer( click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue.